# What do NaNs represent in an SPM β-map?

Tags: fmri, spm

I've estimated a model for an fMRI dataset, so I now have a `beta_*.nii` file for each regressor in my model.  In a seperate step, I've defined ROIs using marsbar and proceeded to extract the corresponding voxels in one of these β-maps.

However, the ROI extracted from said β-map contains only `NaN` values.  Why should there be NaNs at all?  What does such a null value represent in the context of model βs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, this can happen when your ROI is near the edge of the brain as reported [here](https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/webadmin?A2=spm;bcd35412.0804). The thread is pretty old though so this might have been fixed by today and there is another reason in your case.